# Límites de tiempo en colecciones TTL en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Tengo una pregunta, ¿cómo puedo saber el tiempo límite en la recopilación de TTL?

Si tengo una colección con índice expireAfterSeconds en 0 ({expireAfterSeconds: 0}), ¿es posible añadir un documento con expiración de 5, 10 segundos o años? ¿o hay un limite mínimo de tiempo?

Soy consciente de que con este indice puedo elegir el tiempo de caducidad de cada documento independientemente pero revisando la documentación de MongoDB no encuentro información sobre el limite mínimo o máximo para las colecciones TTL (time-to-live) con este indice.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la documentación de MongoDB, para el [índice TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) se desprende lo siguiente: (Traducción propia)

> Un índice TTL hace expirar un documento (o documentos) después de que ha pasado el tiempo en segundos desde el momento que se generó el índice o desde la suma del tiempo indicado en el índice más la cantidad de segundos especificada para su expiración.

Tomando en cuenta esto, un índice TTL es un campo índice cuyo tipo de dato es `date` y que además tiene establecida una propiedad `expireAfterSeconds` de tipo `number` que representa la cantidad de segundos que han de pasar desde el valor almacenado en el índice hasta que el mismo expira.

El límite superior de este valor viene dado por el máximo número entero positivo representable por MongoDB.

Dado que todo tipo `number` en MongoDB es tratado como `floating-point`, entonces el máximo entero positivo que se puede representar usando este tipo de dato será el [máximo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) permitido por Javascript: `(2^53) - 1`. Este valor es `9007199254740991`.

Estos son segundos, por lo tanto si deseamos convertir esto en otras unidades debemos hacer la aritmética adecuada:

```js
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / 60
// Minutos: 150119987579016.53
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / (60*60)
// Horas: 2501999792983.6084
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / (60*60*24)
// Días: 104249991374.31703
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / (60*60*24*7)
// Semanas: 14892855910.616718
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / (60*60*24*30)
// Meses (de 30 días): 3474999712.4772344
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / (60*60*24*365)
// Años (no bisiestos): 285616414.72415626
```

Puedes establecer con seguridad un valor en segundos que represente 10 años: `315360000` y el documento expirará en esa época.

¿La utilidad de establecer un tiempo de expiración tan alto? Eso lo decides tú, sin embargo, como avanza la tecnología y la forma en que ciertas características quedan obsoletas con el paso del tiempo implican que tal vez no sea muy útil establecer un tiempo de expiración en segundos tan alto.

Comment: Mauricio con tu respuesta me has aclarado mis dudas. Hay que tener en cuenta que el proceso que elimina los documentos expirado se realiza cada 60 segundos, por lo que tendra un valos +- 60 segundo aproximadamente. Muchas gracias!